# Access local PATH from IIS deployment

Tags: flask, iis, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a flask API running pytesseract to extract text from a given image using tesseract.

While running the API from terminal, it works like expected.
But once I deploy it on IIS, I start getting: **tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH**.

Is anything I have to do to allow IIS access my local PATH?

In my case, statically specifying tesseract.exe path (*pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'*) is not a solution.

Comment: You need to make sure application pool has permission to access local path. You can change identity of application pool to local system or administrator.

Comment: How can I check those permissions?

Comment: You can change identity of application pool to local system or administrator directly.    https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckEGv.png